# Failed to connect to mongoDb using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, atlas

## **my app.js file has code :**

```
const connectDB = require("./db/connect");
require("dotenv").config()
const app = express();
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const port = 8080;
// listen to server
const start =async () =>{
  try {
    
   await  connectDB(url);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("Connected To DB + App is listening on http://localhost:${port}");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    
  }
};

// call the start function
start();
```

## my connect.js file has code :

```
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const connectDB = (url)=>{
    return  mongoose.connect(url)
}
module.exports = connectDB;
```

## .env file has this variable :

```
MONGO_URI =mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.prrizft.mongodb.net/TaskManager?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

In the above string I am using the correct username and password.

Also I have already add the ip in network (both : from anywhere and my current ip).
I can able to  successfully connect the above string with mongo compass (plus I tested to create a dummy collection and insert document.... everything work fine)

But when I connect the mongoAtlas with node.js using mongoose I will get error[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3J6h.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir5BQ.png)

Comment: Does your cluster have any alerts?

Comment: I have checked there are No alert in cluster

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'dotenv' package requires initializing the library at the beginning of your script.  This can be done in the npm start script or terminal:

```
nodemon -r dotenv/config myscript.js
```

Or if you must include within the code, require('dotenv').config() should be called at the very top of your entry script as in the above:

```js
// myscript.js
require('dotenv').config()

// everything else
```

So in your code example, replace:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectDB = require("./connect");
require("dotenv").config()
const app = express();
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const port = 8080;
// ...
```

With:

```js
require("dotenv").config()
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectDB = require("./connect");
const app = express();
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const port = 8080;
```

And this should solve process.env being in scope when connect.js is loaded.

Comment: I remove the space but this only work once , when I refesh or my nodemon restart it again show the same error

Comment: require("dotenv").config() should be called before any other files are required, otherwise the process.env.* variable you are looking for will not be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

within your mongoDB atlas…
in Network Access… edit IP access list
switch it to “allow access from anywhere”

Answer (score 0):

Note: Please add below packages first

**npm i express, npm i dotenv, npm i mongoose**

**

> App.js (After Modification)

**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectDB = require("./connect");
require("dotenv").config()
const app = express();
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const port = 8080;
// listen to server
const start =async () =>{
  try {
    
   await  connectDB(url);
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("Connected To DB + App is listening on http://localhost:${port}");
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    
  }
};

// call the start function
start();
```

> connect.js (After Modification)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const connectDB = (url)=>{
    return  mongoose.connect(url)
}
module.exports = connectDB;
```

[image]